# Enclose whole div in an <a>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div which I want to surround with an `<a href>`. I have the jQuery to add the `<a href>` after the div but I struggle to set it before and close it after the div.

This is the jQuery code I have:

```
$('.box_service').each(function() {
  var link = $(this).html();
  $(this).contents().wrap('<a href="example.com"></a>');
});
```

It results in this HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="box_service">
    <a href="example.com">
      <div class="inner-row"></div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

However my goal is this structure:

```
<div class="row">
  <a href="example.com">
    <div class="box_service">
      <div class="inner-row"></div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

I can't enter the div before because there are more boxes in this row so I would add the `<a href>` to everything in there

Answer (score 2):

The issue is due to your call to `contents()` which means you're wrapping the elements *inside* `.box_service`, not that element itself. Remove that method call.

Also note that `each()` is redundant, you can do what you require in a single line:

```js
$('.box_service').wrap('<a href="example.com"></a>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="box_service">
    Box service #1
    <div class="inner-row">Inner row #1</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="box_service">
    Box service #2
    <div class="inner-row">Inner row #2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`.content` will wrap the contents of your `div`, you want to wrap the `div` with `<a>` so call `wrap` on the `div` not on contents.

```js
$('.box_service').each(function() {
  var link = $(this).html();
  $(this).wrap('<a href="example.com"></a>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="box_service">
   
    <div class="inner-row"></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.box_service').each(function() {
  var link = $(this).html();
  $(this).wrap('<a href="example.com"></a>');
});
```

You just need to remove `contents()` in between `$(this).wrap()` because `contents()` mean that you are wrapping the children of `$(this)`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `.contents()` in order to wrap around each element with the class `box-service`:

```js
$('.box_service').each(function() {
  $(this).wrap('<a href="example.com"></a>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="box_service">
    <a href="example.com">
      <div class="inner-row"></div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('.box_service').wrap('<a href="example.com"></a>');`

Comment: don't know why this got a downvote as it is the correct answer. http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Comment: Please take the time to describe what the issues are and why this solution helps. Remember, we're here to educate people, not just dump code on them.

Comment: Also not worth a downvote, but have a read of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers

Comment: What's there to comment? It's pretty straightforward: select elements you want to be wrapped and wrap them.